# How to wrap very long text in jgrowl

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-plugins

How do I wrap very long text in jGrowl?

Right now, if the text is long it just tosses out of the page.

Thanks.

Comment: I *assume* you're talking about text that has no spaces is too long for the jgrowl box. Is that right? Do you want it to wrap to a new line at some arbitrary point in the text? What does the text look like? Is it a specific case where this is happening, which would allow us to create a logical break point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Hulk, since we haven't gotten any more info from you, I'm just going to take a stab at a solution.

This will break any long text after 15 characters. (Of course, you can substitute whatever number you want.)

This assumes there are no HTML tags. Just text.

```
var theText = $('.myContainer').text().split(' ')
jQuery.each(theText,function(i,val){
    theText[i] = val.replace(/^(\S{15})(\S+)/,'$1 $2')
})
$('.myContainer').text(theText.join(' '));
```